# Java replaceAll remove spaces from empty lines

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove all spaces from lines in a block of text which contain nothing but spaces, leaving the line breaks in place.

I tried the following:

```
str = " text\n \n \n text";    
str = str
    .replaceAll("\\A +\\n", "\n")
    .replaceAll("(\\n +\\n)", "\n\n")
    .replaceAll("\\n +\\Z", "\n");
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
" text\n\n\n text"
```

but instead it was

```
" text\n\n \n text"
```

The space in the third line of the block had not been removed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please check and select the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag, so that `^` and `$` will match the beginning and end of each line. The problem with your regex is that it is capturing the newline character, so the next match will advance past it, and cannot match.

```
str.replaceAll("(?m)^ +$", "")
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the information. Plenty there to work on - much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to match lines with horizontal spaces only and the `Pattern.MULTILINE` modifier is required for the `^` and `$` anchors to match start and end of *lines* respectively (its embedded option is `(?m)`). Use

```
String str = " text\n \n \n text"; 
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^[\\p{Zs}\t]+$", "");
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/3rKYdo).

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - Multiline mode
- `^` - start of line
- `[\\p{Zs}\t]+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `$` - end of line.

An alternative to `[\p{Zs}\t]` is a pattern to match any whitespace excluding  vertical whitespace symbols. In Java, character class subtraction can be handy: `[\s&&[^\r\n]]` where `[\s]` matches any whitespace and `&&[^\r\n]` excludes a carriage return and newline characters from it. A full pattern would look like [`.replaceAll("(?Um)^[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+$", "")`](http://ideone.com/2W4i80).

Comment: Its always better with details :)

Comment: What is `\p{Zs}`? I can't seem to find it in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Is it the same as `\h`?

Comment: @4castle: Not quite, `\p{Zs}` is a Unicode property class that matches all Unicode horizontal whitespace but a tab character. So, it is not equal to PCRE `\h`.

Comment: @4castle `\p{Zs}` is not explicitly listed, but is indirectly described as a "[class for Unicode category](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode)" (example: `\p{Lu}`) with a link to two paragraphs describing categories. Java 8 uses Unicode 6.2.0, and you can find the categories defined in the [standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-10.html#General_Category_Values), but the http://www.fileformat.info/ site is easier to use: [Unicode Character Categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)

Comment: I added a bit of missing explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use anchors:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^[^\\S\\n]+$", "");
```

Where `^` and `$` match respectively the start and the end of a line when the multiline flag `(?m)` is switched on.

The problem with your pattern is that you use `\\n` around the horizontal whitespaces `replaceAll("(\\n +\\n)", "\n\n")` (simple spaces in your pattern). If you do that you can't obtain contiguous results since you can't match the same character twice.

Note: add eventually `\\r` in the character class *(to exclude it as `\\n`)* if you want to take in account Windows or old Mac end of lines.